# Folder media type repeatedly dropping allowed child nodetypes

Tags: umbraco, media-type

I've got Umbraco 4.7.2 set up with a 3 tier system:

QA -> STAGE -> PROD

I have a Website editor who works in the STAGE environment then publishes to PROD at will. We have a sporadic issue right now with the Folder media type where it drops the settings (checked check boxes) for the allowed child nodes.

This is the folder media type that comes with the Umbraco install with media types added as I created them.

I was considering deleting the media type and recreating it but I've discovered the hard way that is not so smart with Umbraco.

Comment: How is your editor publishing to PROD? In other words, how are you pushing changes from STAGING to PROD? It is not clear from the question. Thanks.

Comment: We're using Courier 2 for transfers. Thanks.

Comment: We are having the same issue where the Folder media type drops the allowed child nodetypes. The result is that images and files cannot be uploaded. We are also using Courier to move content between environments so it looks like Courier could be the cause.